# Projective modules over free groups

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, ra.rings-and-algebras

1. Consider the ring of Laurent polynomials $R := \mathbb{Z}[s,s^{-1}]$  with integer coefficients. Are all projective $R$-modules free? (Let's say left modules by convention.)
2. More generally, let $G$ be the **free** group on a finite set $S$ of generators, and consider the integral group ring $R := \mathbb{Z}G$. Are all projective $R$-modules free? Note that in part (1), $S$ was the singleton $\{ s \}$.
3. Is the answer the same if we allow an infinite set $S$ of generators? Note that the group $G$ itself is infinite either way.

I feel like work of Serre, Swan, Bass, Kaplansky, Suslin, Quillen, and others may be relevant, but I couldn't find the answers.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to your questions is 'yes' and, as you feel, it is a result of Bass:

MR0178032 (31 #2290) 
Bass, Hyman
Projective modules over free groups are free. 
J. Algebra 1 1964 367–373.

Comment: Thank you very much! That answers the case of finitely generated projective modules.

What about non finitely generated projective modules? It looks like Bass's other paper:

MR0143789 (26 #1341) Bass, Hyman Big projective modules are free. Illinois J. Math. 7 1963 24–31

could be useful, but I haven't thought through the details. Any insight?

Comment: Sorry for neglecting the infinitely generated case. Unfortunately, I don't think that second paper of Bass, helps...